# Compiling an assembly source on Mac OS and converting file to object/executable

Tags: macos, gcc, assembly

I'm very new to programming and I had a question about compiling of assembly language on Mac OS. I know that to convert my `.c` to an `.s` I should use `gcc -m32 -S`. However, I already wrote my own `.s` file. I was wondering if it was possible to convert the `.s` I've made so that my Mac can compile it.
The thing is I want to compile both the `.c` and `.s` to verify that they both return the same value.

Comment: gcc itself can be used to compile .s files. Try first with the original one from C (so you know the syntax and content is valid and ready to produce binary). (like `gcc -m32 that_s_file_produced_from_c.s -o binary_name`)

Comment: The `.s` file you created yourself - does it make system calls via `syscall` or `int 0x80`? Is this `.s` file 32-bit or 64-bit code?

Answer (score 1):

Have you simply tried to pass an `.s` file to the compiler? If it is written correctly, then it will just be transformed into an object file and/or an executable.

Here's a minimal example that should work:

```
$ cat 1.s # two lines of a program
.global _main # MacOS expects symbol names decorated
_main: retq # a single return instruction in `main`'s body
$ gcc 1.s # compile it
$ ./a.out # run the resulting program
```

Comment: That definitely won't work this way on Mac (which decorates symbols with leading underscores).  Have you actually tried this on macOS?

Comment: @fuz: but running `gcc -m32 foo.s` will work, where `foo.s` was generated by `gcc -m32 -O3 -S foo.c`, and that's the key point of this answer.  i.e. even if the example is specific to ELF platforms where no leading `_` is used, the overall suggestion is to run `gcc foo.s` on a `.s` that's "written correctly".

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes.  Even though OP's example won't actually work on OS X, it's somehow a good example for how to make stuff work on OS X. -ish?

Comment: @fuz you caught me: never tried to run that example on a MacOS host. I will change my example to use `_main`  instead of `main` — will that be enough?

Comment: @fuz: the `gcc 1.s` / `./aout` part is good.  The OP already has a `.s` they want to compile.  But yes, it's definitely a *better* answer with the example .s fixed to work on OS X, which is why I didn't upvote before. :P  (Grigory: the OP wants `-m32`, and that's required when compiling as well as when assembling + linking.)

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov It is possible.  But without checking on an actual macOS host, I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

After generating assembly code with extension `.s` use this command:

```
gcc -o executable-binary-file-name assembly.s
```

For example, if your assembly file is named as `my.s` and you want your executable name as `my` then use command:

```
gcc -o my my.s
```